# Extracting lines that contain an exact phrase that includes a tab

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file that contains the following lines

```
50[tab]H[tab]1
44[tab]H[tab]2
4[tab]H[tab]3
4[tab]H[tab]4
44[tab]H[tab]5
234[tab]H[tab]6
```

I would like to only extract the last line that starts with the exact phrase "4[tab]H" (so this would be "4[tab]H[tab]4") into another file. I have tried:

```
grep "^4*.H" filein.in | tail -1 >> fileout.out
```

but instead it extracts "44[tab]H[tab]5". I need it to extract the last line that starts with the exact string: "4[tab]H".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ksh93/zsh/bash/mksh/FreeBSD sh:

```
grep $'^4\tH' filein.in | tail -n 1
```

Or in any shell:

```
awk '/^4\tH/ { line=$0; }; END { if(line!="") print line; }' filein.in
```

Answer (score 1):

With gnu sed

```
sed '/^4\tH/h;$bA;N;D;:A;x;/^$/d' infile
```

Comment: Or `gsed -n '/^4\tH/h;${g;/./p;}'`

Comment: Or gsed '/^4\tH/h;$!d;g;/./!d'

Answer (score 0):

You can also reverse the input file line wise using `tac` and then get first match

```bsh
$ # add another \t after H if needed
$ tac ip.txt | grep -m1 $'^4\tH'
4   H   4

$ tac ip.txt | awk -F'\t' '$1=="4" && $2=="H"{print; exit}'
4   H   4
```